# C++ error, Undefined reference class

Tags: c++, class

Why does codeblocks give this error "Undefined reference to class::classfunction()"
It happens when a class is created in a separated file.All of these files are in the same folder

This is the main .cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Class2.h"

using namespace std;

main()
{
    Class2 classObject;
    cout<<"I'm class2"<<endl;

}
```

class header file

```
#ifndef CLASS2_H
#define CLASS2_H


class Class2
{
    public:
        Class2();
        ~Class2();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // CLASS2_H
```

class cpp file

```
#include "Class2.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

Class2::Class2()
{
    cout<<"Hello, I'm Constructor"<<endl;
}

Class2::~Class2()
{
    cout<<"Yo!! I'm Destructor"<<endl;
}
```

error is "undefined reference to Class2::Class2()"

Comment: You never defined "class::classfunction()"

Comment: sorry, the error is "undefined reference to Class2::Class2()"

Comment: maybe try to switch the positions of include statements in the class cpp file?

Comment: tried switching their order. still gives same error

Comment: What command(s) are you using to compile and link the code?

Comment: The is a *linker* error. In other words, the linker doesn't know it's also supposed to look in class.cpp. If you're using an IDE then it might not be part of the target. If you're using the command line then compile with `g++ main.cpp class.cpp`

Comment: i'm using codeblocks. and its build & run option

Answer (score 5):

You need to link both `main.o` and `class.o` into your executable. The exact command depends on your compiler and OS. For g++ the command would look something like

```
g++ -o main main.cpp class.cpp
```

Comment: sorry but where to enter this kind of code? I'm compiling directly through codeblocks. not via a terminal

Comment: @user3286581: I am no expert on CodeBlocks, but you probably need to create a project containing the two source files: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project