# C++ Undefined reference to `main (.text+0x24)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have some problems with compiling my program since adding .h files to it.

The error I'm getting looks like this.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried adding int main() to minesClass.cpp but it didn't fix the problem

Program contains three files: main.cpp, minesClass.h, minesClass.cpp

main.cpp

```
#include "minesClass.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <time.h>

#ifndef MINESBOARD_H__
#define MINESBOARD_H__

int main()
{
  MinesweeperBoard board(10, 10, GameMode::NORMAL);

  board.getMines();

  board.debug_display();

}

#endif
```

minesClass.cpp

```
#include "minesClass.h"

#define MINESBOARD_H__
#ifndef MINESBOARD_H__

MinesweeperBoard::MinesweeperBoard(int width, int height, GameMode mode)
{
  for (int column = 0; column < height; column++) 
  {
    for (int row = 0; row < width; row++)
    {
      board[column][row].hasFlag = false;
      board[column][row].isRevealed = false;
    }
  }
}

void MinesweeperBoard::getMines(GameMode mode)  
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    switch (mode)
    {
    case 1:
        EASY;

        for (int column = 0; column < height; column++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < width; row++)
            {
                int minePropability = RAND_MAX * 0.1;
                int num = rand();

                if (num <= minePropability)
                {
                    board[column][row].hasMine = 1;
                }
                else
                    board[column][row].hasMine = 0;
            }
        }

        break;
    case 2:
        NORMAL;

        for (int column = 0; column < height; column++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < width; row++)
            {
                int minePropability = RAND_MAX * 0.2;
                int num = rand();

                if (num <= minePropability)
                {
                    board[column][row].hasMine = 1;
                }
                else
                    board[column][row].hasMine = 0;
            }
        }

        break;
    case 3:
        HARD;

        for (int column = 0; column < height; column++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < width; row++)
            {
                int minePropability = RAND_MAX * 0.3;
                int num = rand();

                if (num <= minePropability)
                {
                    board[column][row].hasMine = 1;
                }
                else
                    board[column][row].hasMine = 0;
            }
        }

        break;
    case 4:
        DEBUG;

        break;
    default:

        break;
    }
    
}

void MinesweeperBoard::debug_display() const
{

for (int column = 0; column < height; column++)
  {
    for (int row = 0; row < width; row++)
    {
      std::cout << "[";
      if (board[column][row].hasMine)
        std::cout << "M";
      else
        std::cout << ".";
      if (board[column][row].isRevealed)
        std::cout << "o";
      else
        std::cout << ".";
      if (board[column][row].hasFlag)
        std::cout << "f";
      else
        std::cout << ".";
      std::cout << "]";
    }
    std::cout << width<<height<<std::endl;
  }

}

#endif
```

minesClass.h

```
#include <iostream>

#define MINESBOARD_H__
#ifndef MINESBOARD_H__

enum GameMode
{
  DEBUG,
  EASY,
  NORMAL,
  HARD
};

struct Field
{
  bool hasMine;
  bool hasFlag;
  bool isRevealed;
};

class MinesweeperBoard
{

  Field board[100][100];
  int width;
  int height;
  
public:

  MinesweeperBoard(int width, int height, GameMode mode);

  void debug_display() const;
  
  void getMines(GameMode mode);
};

#endif
```

I've looked through similar questions asked with "undefined reference to `main" but most of them were based on missing int main().

Comment: Can you post your build settings?

Comment: Get rid of the include guards in your .cpp files.

Comment: Include guards in a cpp file is odd.

Comment: Unfortunately, the program has to be based on my teachers format and she is very pragmatic about these guards so they are necessary

Comment: Never put header guards in a .cpp file.

Comment: If you are using VSCode, did you modify your `tasks.json` file to build your executable with more than 1 cpp file? The default behavior of VSCode is to build only the active file into the executable. The official Microsoft documentation tells you how to fix this. Here is the documentation of that: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: There no return value of an int in your main. I'm not a C++ guy but that caught my attention. Also, it's a good idea to include your Makefile or a line with the g++ commands you are using to compile.

Comment: int main no longer has to return a value since I believe c++11. It's the only function where this is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Your include guards are wrong.

Usually `.cpp` won't need include guards, so you should remove the lines with `#ifndef`, `#define`, and `#endif` from your `.cpp` files.

Then, you should change

```
#define MINESBOARD_H__
#ifndef MINESBOARD_H__
```

in your `minesClass.h` to

```
#ifndef MINESBOARD_H__
#define MINESBOARD_H__
```

Otherwise, using `#ifndef` after using `#define` will always prevent it from using lines after that.

Comment: Unfortunately after excluding these guards i get: 

`/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUm4xMS.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `MinesweeperBoard::MinesweeperBoard(int, int, GameMode)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `MinesweeperBoard::getMines(GameMode)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `MinesweeperBoard::debug_display() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ error, Undefined reference class - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643394/c-error-undefined-reference-class) How are you building (compiling and linking) your program?

Comment: I'm using gcc version 9.3.0 , compiling using g++ if that's an answer to your question

Comment: Also solution from your link didn't fix the problem

Comment: From the errors it really looks like you did not modify your `tasks.json` and thus you are each time you are building only the active `.cpp` file and thus getting errors about functions in the other cpp files. You need to build all .cpp files into your executable.